# How to make this descending pitch heavy sound?

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer, replication

I'd like to achieve something similar to that descending pitch heavy sound as heard here : https://clyp.it/jf0uqdoq#
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a SINE wave signal (yes read on)
2. Let it dive an octave (either by gradual resampling, generator pitch automation or LFO / Wheel pitch control on your synth)
3. Add a percussive hit to the start (like a kick drum)
4. Feed that into a distortion/overdrive/clipper (consider a guitar amp simulator).

The overdrive/distortion will transform the sine wave form towards a square wave as the signal tops are clipped away.

[image]

This overdrive step is quite crucial to the way the initial hit also influences the distortion of the sine. A square might work out too, but I don't think that is what is going on here. It sounds much like a subkick bass dive sample distorted heavily and these are mostly made of diving sines with a kick/floortom sample in the start.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man that sounds like the Camel Crusher plugin if I ever heard it!

Try putting a square wave with a pitch envelope through Camel Crusher (or the next best thing).

Answer (score -2):

try adding a kick layer too with heavy saturation. enough to where it sounds like that lol

Answer (score -3):

drop sound sample (reverse riser)

with distortion / bitcrusher